# what is the running time of Substring in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, substring

So I'm trying to parse strings being read over an RS-232 serial port and the Substring function is the culprit.  Is it O(N) run-time?  Is there a faster way to chop up the string into pieces which I can then parse?

Comment: I can hardly believe that if you're sending strings over RS-232, the bottleneck could be in `String.Substring()`... How do you need to chop it up? Anyway, it's definitely O(N)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got my wrist slapped the last time I quoted this without the full quote, so I'll do it properly this time:

> Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: **premature optimization is the root of all evil**. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%

As Matthew Watson points out, I very much doubt `Substring` is what you need to be worrying about.

Now, this might seem to you to be quite a condescending answer, but if programmers are coding with "must be fast" all the time; then in my opinion their brain isn't concentrating on what they are supposed to be doing, which is writing functional code that solves a particular problem.

Write code that is visibly *fast enough*, and then as that quote says - if there is a true problem with the performance (e.g., your invoice run is taking 5 hours for 20 pdfs), then you may need to start looking at what is taking up the time.